# File signature for .db file needed after failed restore

Tags: data-recovery

I have just performed a factory reset and restore using CWM on Android custom ROM 'Neatrom'.

The restore deosnt seem to have completed properly, as the apps are there but the app data seems to be missing.

As a result, I have lost my notes and tasks ('My phone Explorer NOtes' and 'My Phone explorer Tasks').  I am trying to recover deleted and lost files using Yodot Data Recovery for android.  The files are , I believe, 'notes.db' and /or 'notes.db-journal', but '.db' or '.db-journal', are not default file types in Yodot, and need to be entered as a 'new file type'.

It asks for: 
1) the file signature of this file type, in Hex,
2) THe file size
3) THe file offset
4) A Description of the type

Could anyone let me know what these details would be?  I have tried with the information on .db and .db-journal files in the online file signature database, but 'db-journal' isnt a file type in the database.  'db' has various signatures.  Using them, the 'notes.db' file wasnt found when I performed the search.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The format of these files is [described in SQLite's documentation](http://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html).

The db file is the main database and starts with the string `"SQLite format 3\000"` (note that `\000` is the zero byte or ASCII NUL).

The db-journal file is the journal for the database. You only need it if the database was open when you performed the factory reset (that is, if the app was running and in the middle of writing the database). It starts with the following bytes: 0xd9, 0xd5, 0x05, 0xf9, 0x20, 0xa1, 0x63, 0xd7.